# What is the minimum release level to use Branch deeplinks with a playstore url?

Tags: android, branch.io, google-play-console

I am currently putting an app into production.

Before doing so publicly, I would like to test if my deeplinks work properly when providing a playstore URL in my branch dashboard.

What is the most appropriate release level to do so (internal vs alpha vs beta) ?

I tried internal and alpha, but none of them seems to provide a playstore URL accessible by Branch. If I try to create a Beta version, it will be opened to at least 1000 users.

Comment: I think beta can be invite only / those with the link. So i doubt you will have issues using beta. Sign your google account up for beta, install, then try the links using the normal playstore url

Comment: Adding on to @Doomsknight's answer, Google has recently pushed out an internal testing track where you can make your APK available to internal testers very quickly via the Play Store. Something like a pre-alpha (totally invented term!) stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in case you push it to production,then it will work.Unless not.

And trust me,as I worked on this before,I have experienced that if normally it is redirecting then by providing a playstore URL in your branch dashboard also it will work.

Comment: I could not find a way to do that before production either. Providing a play store URL is what I ended up doing because my app was not found in the Google Play Search field.

Answer (score -1):

Jackie from Branch here.

You can leverage Branch's test sandbox environment by using your Branch test key instead of the live key.

Think of Test app and Live app as separate apps in the Branch system that are simply available from the same Dashboard for convenience. There is no data crossover between the Live environment and the Test sandbox, both offer identical configuration options, and you use different Branch keys to access each one. Links respect the configuration settings of the Branch key under which they are created, such as below:

app.example.com
app.test-example.com

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough. I am already using those 2 environments (LIVE and TEST). My problem is that I want to test the use case where a user clicks a deeplink (without having the app installed) and gets redirected to the playstore using Google Play Search (as stated in my LIVE config), **before going to production** . At the moment I only use the TEST config where my user is redirected to a custom URL that provides him the APK.